# How to connect to mulitple couchbase clusters from spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I need to connect to bucket1 and bucket2 which are in cluster 1 and cluster 2 respectively from my spring application

bucket1-> cluster1

bucket2 -> cluster2

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow . Elaborate the problem properly.

Answer (score 2):

Some of this is commented out, but will work when uncommented.  It's from the Config class in spring-data-couchbase/src/test/java. Look at the methods from the bottom up to understand the mechanisms.
Notice that I prepend 'my' to many methods, because if there is an @Bean method in the superclass with the same name, then the value of that bean will be used instead of the result of executing the method.
myCouchbaseClientFactory() will create a couchbaseClientFactory with the specified args.
The result can be used by  myCouchbaseTemplate/myReactiveCouchbaseTemplate to make a templates.
Those templates can be used by the two configure*RespositoryOperationsMapping methods to map repository operations.

```
@Override
public void configureReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping(ReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping baseMapping) {
    try {
        // comment out references to 'protected' and 'mybucket' - they are only to show how multi-bucket would work
        // ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate personTemplate =
        // myReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("protected"),new MappingCouchbaseConverter());
        // baseMapping.mapEntity(Person.class, personTemplate); // Person goes in "protected" bucket
        // ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate userTemplate = myReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("mybucket"),new
        // MappingCouchbaseConverter());
        // baseMapping.mapEntity(User.class, userTemplate); // User goes in "mybucket"
        // everything else goes in getBucketName() ( which is travel-sample )
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
@Override
public void configureRepositoryOperationsMapping(RepositoryOperationsMapping baseMapping) {
    try {
        // comment out references to 'protected' and 'mybucket' - they are only to show how multi-bucket would work
        // CouchbaseTemplate personTemplate = myCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("protected"),new
        // MappingCouchbaseConverter());
        // baseMapping.mapEntity(Person.class, personTemplate); // Person goes in "protected" bucket
        // CouchbaseTemplate userTemplate = myCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("mybucket"),new
        // MappingCouchbaseConverter());
        // baseMapping.mapEntity(User.class, userTemplate); // User goes in "mybucket"
        // everything else goes in getBucketName() ( which is travel-sample )
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
// do not use reactiveCouchbaseTemplate for the name of this method, otherwise the value of that bean
// will be used instead of the result of this call (the client factory arg is different)
public ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate myReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(CouchbaseClientFactory couchbaseClientFactory,
        MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter) {
    return new ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(couchbaseClientFactory, mappingCouchbaseConverter);
}
// do not use couchbaseTemplate for the name of this method, otherwise the value of that been
// will be used instead of the result from this call (the client factory arg is different)
public CouchbaseTemplate myCouchbaseTemplate(CouchbaseClientFactory couchbaseClientFactory,
        MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter) {
    return new CouchbaseTemplate(couchbaseClientFactory, mappingCouchbaseConverter);
}
// do not use couchbaseClientFactory for the name of this method, otherwise the value of that bean will
// will be used instead of this call being made ( bucketname is an arg here, instead of using bucketName() )
public CouchbaseClientFactory myCouchbaseClientFactory(String bucketName) {
    return new SimpleCouchbaseClientFactory(getConnectionString(), authenticator(), bucketName);
}
```